# unsupported operand type error while evaluating gradient using sympy

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to minimize this function -(y+47)*sin(sqrt(abs((x/2)+y+47))) - x*sin(sqrt(abs(x-(y+47)))) which is the ***eggholder function*** by using gradient descent method and inbuilt sympy library to evaluate the gradients but i am getting error.

Error message:

[image: error message]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import math
import sympy as sym

x,y = sym.symbols('x y')

 #objective function
def objective(p): 
    x = p[0]
    y = p[1]
    return -(y+47)*sym.sin(sym.sqrt(abs((x/2)+y+47))) - x*sym.sin(sym.sqrt(abs(x-(y+47))))

 #gradient wrt x
def gradient_1(p): 
    g0 = sym.diff(objective([x,y]),x)
    return g0.subs(x,p[0]).subs(y,p[1])

#gradient wrt y
def gradient_2(p):
    g1 = sym.diff(objective([x,y]),y)
    return g1.subs(x,p[0]).subs(y,p[1])

#initial guess
x = [-450,-450]

#learning rate
alpha = 0.135

#initialization
iter = 0
e = 1000
grad = np.array([])
error = np.array([])

#gradient descent 
while e > 0.000000001:
    t = objective(x)
    grad = [gradient_1(x),gradient_2(x)]
    change = np.dot(-alpha,grad)
    x = np.add(x,change)
    e = abs(objective(x)-t)
    error = np.append(error,e)
    iter = iter+1
    print("ITERATION NUMBER = ",iter)

#printing optimized values
print(x)
#plotting error v/s iteration
i = np.arange(1,iter+1)    
plt.plot(i,error)
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.ylabel("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second iteration of the while, the variable `x` is not a of type int but of type list. You can see it if you print the type of the variables x and y inside the function `objective()`.

```
def objective(p): 
    x = p[0]
    y = p[1]
    #print(type(p))
    print("Iteration")
    print("x:", type(x))
    print("y:", type(y))
    return -(y+47)*sym.sin(sym.sqrt(abs((x/2)+y+47))) - x*sym.sin(sym.sqrt(abs(x-(y+47))))
```

Output:

```
Iteration
x: <class 'int'>
y: <class 'int'>
Iteration
x: <class 'list'>
y: <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

Comment: Thank you @DavideBrex. Any clues as to why this is happening would be highly appreciated .

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know why is happening. It might be related to: `g0 = sym.diff(objective([x,y]),x)`. Really sorry, good luck!

Comment: I figured it out, it was because i was assigning the same variable 'x' to the solution vector as well. #initial guess
x = [-450,-450] . The issue got solved after I assigned a different variable to solution vector. Appreciate your concern.